# Call batch with param

Tags: batch-file, console, cmd

How to execute the call command with param?

I want to do something like this:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

... but it does not seem to work. The following does not work, too:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86"
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first should work. try modifying the `...vcvarsall.bat` file by adding

```
echo %*
pause
```

If CMD reports `x86` then it is indeed "working" and the problem is with the `...vcvarsall.bat` file.

Beyond that, we'd need to know what you regard as "working".

Comment: it is stated that the path is too long

Answer (score 2):

This works, session protocol:

```
>type "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
@echo %*

>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
x86
```

So it seems, this is not the issue.